# how to get SVM coefficients out when using custom kernel

Tags: python, kernel, svm

For a binary classification problem, I am using SVC (in sklearn) with a custom kernel (anova kernel). I implemented the kernel as a function and passed that function to SVC. After model fitting, I need to get the model coefficient out so that it can be implemented in production for classifying new data points. So, question is how to get the coefficients?

When looking for coef_ parameter, I get the message - "coef_ is only available when using a linear kernel". Also, support_vectors_ array is empty.[image: Also, support_vectors_ array is empty]

Comment: Even though "coef_" says the same error in my case, I get values for support_vectors_  while applying SVM to classification. coef_ is a read-only property derived from dual_coef_ and support_vectors_, so check either clf.dual_coef_ has values or not.

Comment: If you are looking for the coefficients of the support vector, you can use the `dual_coef_` attribute.